# How to set responsive curvy background image..CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a curvy background image but I can not set responsiveness for that I have tried to cut bottom and top curvy parts and add :before and :after to div and set as background but still need to works lots of media queries and positioning absolute almost every pixel what is the best practice for that ?`

```css
.homepage-client-about_wrapper {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  background: #8B47E7;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
  position: relative;
  
  //  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  //      background: transparent;
  //     }

  &:before {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: url("../assets/img/v-top.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 20rem;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -28%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
       @media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
           background: url("../assets/img/v-top-small.png") no-repeat cover;
           height: 14rem;
           top: -19%;
      }
       @media screen and (max-width: 1006px) {
           top: -18%;
      }
       @media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
       background: url("../assets/img/xss.png") no-repeat cover;
       height: 10rem;
       top: -12%;

      }
     
  }
  &:after {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: url("../assets/img/v-bottom.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left center ;
    height: 36rem;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50%;
    left: -.3%;
    z-index: -1;
      @media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
           background: url("../assets/img/v-bottom-small.png") no-repeat cover center;
           height: 28rem;
           bottom: -40%;
      }
        @media screen and (max-width: 1006px) {
           bottom: -37%;
      }
       @media screen and (max-width: 870px) {
       background: url("../assets/img/xssbottom.png") no-repeat cover;
       height: 21rem;
       bottom: -27%;
      }
       @media screen and (max-width: 778px) {
       bottom: -26%;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        background: url("../assets/img/v-bottom-xxs.png") no-repeat contain;
        height: 15rem;
        bottom: -20%;
        z-index: 1;
      }
  }
}
```

`[image]

[image]

**Result is like that**
[image]

Comment: What about using `z-index` and overlaying the images ? Also you can just set the cut images to have `100%` width and it should be just fine.

Comment: I have already set width:100% for cut images for example my fist cut iamge width 1530px if I will resize browser to 1300px left side of my cut image is overflowing not resizing as I need. So I decided to set different sized images width media queries

Comment: So it also cant help and need a lot of fixes for every screensize . Is there have any effective way for that ?

Comment: @ZombieChowder I have edited post and add result

Comment: Can you provide a js fiddle? It'll be easier to solve your problem then